# Symfony 2 Dom Crawler: how to get only text() in Element

Tags: symfony, domcrawler

Using Dom Crawler to get only text (without tag).

```
$html = EOT<<<
  <div class="coucu">
    Get Description <span>Coucu</span>
  </div>
EOT;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$crawler = $crawler->filter('.coucu')->first()->text();
```

*output:* Get Description Coucu

*I want to output (only):* Get Description

***UPDATE:***

I found a solution for this: (but it's really bad solution)

```
...
$html = $crawler->filter('.coucu')->html();
// use strip_tags_content in https://php.net/strip_tags
$html = strip_tags_content($html,'span');
```

Comment: No, I'm not use jQuery

Comment: I don't think there is a method for this but you can try $text = $crawler->filter('.coucu')->first()->extract(array('_text')); i believe it will return the same result but still worth a shot

Comment: I have used extract function(). But it's not work.

Comment: I guess that `strip_tags_content` is from https://gist.github.com/marcanuy/7651298. I personally don't like regexes for HTML, they lead to bad stuff (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same situation. I ended up going with:

```
$html = $crawler->filter('.coucu')->html();
$html = explode("<span", $html);
echo trim($html[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the criteria within your question, I think you would be best served by modifying your CSS Selector to: `$crawler = $crawler->filter('div.coucu > span')`

From there you can go `$span_text = $crawler->text();`

or to simplify things: `$text = $crawler->filter('div.coucu > span')->text();`

The [text() method](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_text) returns the value of the first item within the list.

Comment: I want to get "Get Description Coucu".

Answer (score 1):

```php
function extractCurrentText(Crawler $crawler)
{
  $clone = new Crawler();
  $clone->addHTMLContent("<body><div>" . $crawler->html() . "</div></body>", "UTF-8");
  $clone->filter("div")->children()->each(function(Crawler $child) {
    $node = $child->getNode(0);
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
  });
  return $clone->text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML-removing solution it's based on regexes to strip HTML away (bad idea [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)), and the explode solution is limited.

I came up going by difference: get all the text, then remove the non-own text with `str_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

This works nicely without hacky workarounds:

```
$crawler->filter('.coucu')->children()->each(function (Crawler $crawler) {
    $crawler->getNode(0)->parentNode->removeChild($crawler->getNode(0));
});
$crawler->text(); // Get Description
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$div = $crawler->filter('.coucu')->html();
$span = $crawler->filter('.coucu > span')->html();
$text = strip_tags(str_replace($span,'',$div));
```