# PHP Goutte Web Scraping

Tags: php, web-scraping, goutte, domcrawler

I want to **scrape** this:

```
<a class="pdt_title"> 
  Japan Sun Apple - Fuji
  <span class="pdt_Tweight">2 per pack</span>
</a>
```

This is my code:

```
use Goutte\Client;
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.fairprice.com.sg/searchterm/apple');
foreach ($crawler->filter('a.pdt_title') as $node) {
    print $node->nodeValue."\n";
}
```

I only want to **scrape** the text inside "a" tag without the text inside "span" tag.
How to only get the text inside "a" tag?

Comment: Please show the code where `$client` is defined.

Comment: @Davіd i have edit the code..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony 2 Dom Crawler: how to get only text() in Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116485/symfony-2-dom-crawler-how-to-get-only-text-in-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the HTML markup, the text node that you want falls into the first child of the anchor. Since each `$node` is an instance of `DOMElement`, you can use `->firstChild` (targeting the text node), then use `->nodeValue`:

```
foreach ($crawler->filter('a.pdt_title') as $node) {
    echo $node->firstChild->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Another alternative is to use xpath, via `->filterXpath()`, its in the docs by the way:

```
foreach ($crawler->filterXpath('//a[@class="pdt_title"]/text()') as $text) {
    echo $text->nodeValue , "\n";
}
```

Related docs:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

The xpath query just targets the anchor with that class and then the text.

Or another one liner. It returns an array, extracting the texts:

```
$output = $crawler->filterXpath('//a[@class="pdt_title"]/text()')->extract(array('_text'));
```

Related DOM Docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php